# Where to put document files and working files?

Tags: android

I'm developing an ebook reader app for Android. The special books for this app are zipped files of some html/css/js/image/... files which are in a server and will be downloaded by the app. Each zipped file may have 1-5 MB and if extracted, a lot more than that.

I was wondering, regarding to android guidelines, where is suitable to

1. Put the zipped book files?
2. Put the extracted files when they are being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you actually need to save that data when app finishes, you should use sd-card, since it has more space, but if you only download image one time, just to show it on screen than use internal storage. Also consider your lowest API since that will be phone with least storage, and your app needs to work there as well as on new devices. Either way if you have to make several files while extracting data, use internal storage because it will be faster, and move it later to sd card if you actually need to save it.

Comment: OK. Then in case of internal memory, what directory should be used? `Context.getDir()` or else?

Comment: File file = new File(activity.getFilesDir(),file_name);